# how to get all value in list in same time

Tags: python

following show the my list value (variable is "data")

```
[{'letters': ['R', 'V', 'X', 'U', 'M', 'Z', 'B', 'O', 'R'],
  'words': ['RVX', 'BOM', 'RUB', 'RUZ', 'MBOOO', 'RMR'],
  'score': 51},
 {'letters': ['P', 'X', 'M', 'R', 'D', 'S', 'I', 'C', 'E'],
  'words': ['PXM', 'RDS', 'ICE', 'PRI', 'DSCE', 'PXM', 'MRE'],
  'score': 54}]
```

Then I used the following code

```
print(*data)
```

output was

```
{'letters': ['R', 'V', 'X', 'U', 'M', 'Z', 'B', 'O', 'R'], 'words': ['RVX', 'BOM', 'RUB', 'RUZ', 'MBOOO', 'RMR'], 'score': 51} {'letters': ['P', 'X', 'M', 'R', 'D', 'S', 'I', 'C', 'E'], 'words': ['PXM', 'RDS', 'ICE', 'PRI', 'DSCE', 'PXM', 'MRE'], 'score': 54}
```

but I want to get that output with comma with saparate two JSON

Like this

```
{'letters': ['R', 'V', 'X', 'U', 'M', 'Z', 'B', 'O', 'R'], 'words': ['RVX', 'BOM', 'RUB', 'RUZ', 'MBOOO', 'RMR'], 'score': 51},
{'letters': ['P', 'X', 'M', 'R', 'D', 'S', 'I', 'C', 'E'], 'words': ['PXM', 'RDS', 'ICE', 'PRI', 'DSCE', 'PXM', 'MRE'], 'score': 54}
```

Any one can help me

Thank you

Comment: What's the reason for wanting that output format? Your first example is conceptually valid JSON, your second is not - so what is the specific reason? You can get your last output by doing `json.dumps(data[0]) + ',' + json.dumps(data[1])`, but this seems like a very weird output format without any practical programmatic use.

Comment: @MatsLindh None of this is valid JSON.

Comment: @KellyBundy OK, sorry for the inaccuracies, OP asked about having valid JSON as the output; The first is at least close, except for the string terminators.

Comment: @MatsLindh With "first", do you mean their "input", the dict? I thought with first/second you meant their current/desired output. (Still none of them are JSON, and I totally agree with you that they're trying to produce hard-to-use data and likely shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
print(*data, sep=",\n")
```

That will put your items on separate lines, with commas after all but the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
print(*data, sep=',')
```

Comment: I think it should be `sep=',\n'`